# Laravel 5.3 Personal access token 500

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm trying to set up my custom API with Passport (well, I'm already halfway through, just need to build my authentication). Whenever I'm trying to create a personal access token from my Passport dashboard (/home route), I get a 'Whoops, something went wrong!' error.

This comes from my Vue component (PersonalAccessTokens.vue), and my console logs me a 500 internal server error at the Post route for storing personal access tokens...

\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@store is the method responsible but I can't seem to find something outof the ordinary as I did exactly follow the Laracasts video about Passport

Anyone else experiencing this problem ?

TIA!

Comment: What's the error in the error log...?

Comment: Nothing, the error comes from my Vue component I guess, it should be in the /logs directory right? Assuming the server returns a 500 it should be logged somewhere..

Comment: @FabianTjoeAOn if you're using chrome open developer console, go to `network` tab, then perform request. You should see request you've just performed. Click on it, then select `preview` from this request's tab. This, or just look at `storage/log/laravel.log` and see stack trace :)

Comment: Oh wow thanks, my logs are empty but didn't know that you could use the network tab like this. It says "ErrorException in ClientRepository.php line 66:
Trying to get property of non-object".

Which refers to the function personalAccessClient():

public function personalAccessClient()
    {
        if (Passport::$personalAccessClient) {
            return Client::find(Passport::$personalAccessClient);
        } else {
            return PersonalAccessClient::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->client;
        }
    }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out.

Apparently it can't read my personal access token client, that you should generate when setting up Passport by using the command: `php artisan passport:install`

Running this command solves my problem.

Reference:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/create-personal-access-token-in-laravel-passport-is-failing

Answer (score 3):

A little more info on this as I've been having the same problem. You need to run:

`php artisan passport:install`

each time you refresh your migrations by doing:

`php artisan migrate:refresh`

To deal with this I've just added a script to `package.json` which uses [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) so I can do it in one command:

```
"scripts": {
  // Other scripts
  "migrate:refresh": "php artisan migrate:refresh",
  "passport:install": "php artisan passport:install",
  "db:refresh": "npm-run-all --sequential migrate:refresh passport:install"
}
```

Now I can just do:

`npm run db:refresh`