# Internal Server Error[500] when using personal-access-token to access laravel api

Tags: php, laravel, passport.js, laravel-passport

(This is not a duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 Personal access token 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563147/laravel-5-3-personal-access-token-500). There is a problem with creating the token, but I have no issue with creating the token, my token is simply not accepted in the authentication)

I have a setup using laravel/passport on apache. I've followed the installation routine in https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#installation and also  There I created a mixed application. A part is using standard laravel, and there is a complex component using vue+vuex. My authentication works as follows: I use laravel standard web authentication and on user login I create a fresh personal-access-token.

When the vue component is created it retrieves the token successfully using:

```
window.axios.get(`/oauth/personal-access-tokens`)
```

When I query the api I hand over the token:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+context.rootState.user.token;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
window.axios.get(`/api/userfavs`)...
```

The complete header

```
Accept  application/json
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Authorization   Bearer 43c7fbc2b96d67d36749ad6…cf6692eb7d21dbc15d4196c1212bd
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkNrNSswZER…jOTA5MTA3ZjMxOTk4NWEifQ%3D%3D
Host    localhost
Referer http://localhost/vegbed/1/edit
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0
X-CSRF-TOKEN    tbVdEArmqXzdEGGwwd2eYFnL0gwKs4dW01aSrKz1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
X-XSRF-TOKEN    eyJpdiI6IkNr
```

The route:

```
Route::get('userfavs/','Api\UserFavController@index')->middleware('auth:api');
```

The response is:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api_token' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `api_token` = 43c7fbc2b96d67d36749ad6df2278e4e69d755909dfc2de3400cf6692eb7d21dbc15d4196c1212bd limit 1)

Thats what my auth.php looks like:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Show us the Laravel error either from the response or from `laravel.log`. It's a server error, the frontend code isn't particularly helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 Personal access token 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563147/laravel-5-3-personal-access-token-500)

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the other question. I see the SQL error, for sure there is no column 'api_token' in the column users, there is a line "api_token" in the oauth_access_tokens. But I don't know why he is doing this stupid query.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Would you also put the contents of your `config/auth.php` file in to your question?

Comment: Just updated the question, I use Version 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

laravel use api_token if you write token in guard in your config.php,,
you need api_token field in your table if you use token in your api guards.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver'   => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
  ]
```

so if you want to use passport then change the driver in API to passport like this :

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver'   => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
  ]
```

when it still get same error after you change it to passport, **clear your app with artisan first. clear the cache, config, and view**..

Comment: I had the auth.php file accordingly. I cleaned my laravel using
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear. It seems the 500 is gone but still authentication does not work (401)